# Read and write a file using filereader and filewriter

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter

I'm writing a simple Java application and I'm stuck with filereader and filewriter. My problem is how to search "birds" and output dove, pigeon and parrot.

Sample text file.

```
{ :birds:
1a:dove
2a:pigeon }    
${ :reptiles:
1a:snake
2a:crocodile }
${ :birds:
1a:parrot
2a:dove }
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class bspReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    bspReader fileReaderService = new bspReader();
    fileReaderService.performExecute("birds");
}

public void performExecute(String inputPattern) {
    List<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/desktop"); 
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {


}

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How are you stuck? Where is your attempt to write to file, to read to file?

Comment: Maybe try using [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)?

Answer (score 1):

You file does not seem to be consistent for all the lines, 1 starts with `'$'` while one doesn't. There are 2 sequences in 1 line and in the other there is just one. For that, let's assuming the Strings and the `inputPattern` is contained within the 'curly braces' - `{}`

To that effect we can easily Split the individual lines in your while loop with a suitable regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
```

For every line within your `while` loop, let's put each matching group encountered within a `list`:

```
while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(strLine);
                while (regexMatcher.find()) {
                    if (regexMatcher.group().contains(inputPattern))
                        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
                }
            }
```

See the `inputPattern` being used to selectively check the group matching your requirement.

To showcase the next steps, lets split each item in the `matchList` on a `space` and subsequently put this in a second list:

```
List<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : matchList.toArray(new String[matchList.size()])) {
                System.out.println(str);
                birdList.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s")));
            }
```

If I now print the elements of the resulting list ignoring the `inputPattern` and the braces, you would get you individual lines with dove, pigeon etc:

```
for (String str : birdList.toArray(new String[birdList.size()])) {
                if (!str.matches("^.*?(\\{|\\}|birds).*$"))
                    System.out.println(str);
            }
```

**Output:**

```
1a:dove
2a:pigeon
1a:parrot
2a:dove
```

Extract the words from your individual lines using another `regex` `indexOf` etc. Also, you an make it more generic and reduce the number of `Collections` I have used for the concept.

**EDIT:** Complete source below:
**EDIT 2: Based on the changed source file above**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringManip fileReaderService = new StringManip();
        fileReaderService.performExecute("birds");
    }

    public void performExecute(String inputPattern) {
    try {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                "C:/users/XYZ/desktop/birds.txt");
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));

        String strLine;

        List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");

        while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(strLine);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(builder.toString());
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            if (regexMatcher.group().contains(inputPattern))
                matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
        }

        List<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String str : matchList.toArray(new String[matchList.size()])) {
            //System.out.println(str);
            birdList.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s")));
        }

        for (String str : birdList.toArray(new String[birdList.size()])) {
            if (!str.matches("^.*?(\\{|\\}|birds).*$"))
                System.out.println(str);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @PopoFibo thank you for your response. The '$' sign is a just a separator. May I request to please explain to me the use of below code Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}"); especially those inside the parentheses. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sishan I'm trying to get all the elements separated which are within `{}`. Try copying `{([^}]*)}` [here](http://regex101.com/) (notice, without escape sequences) to get the specific explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I know what regex is. I tried running your code but the output shows nothing.

Comment: @Sishan that'd depend on your file location and its contents. Are you sure you are pointing to the right place? I created a file with the exact contents as you've mentioned provided the right location and it works just fine

Comment: I'd checked my file content and its location is correct but still can't get an output in my eclipse console. :(

Comment: @Sishan so executing it you don't get any exceptions or output in your console?

Comment: @Sishan Oh I see, your file format in the question is different from what it looked like initially. Look at the edited code above, I have separated the concerns by dumping the file contents to a builder and then regular parsing with regex. See if it prints anything in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to implement the while loop.

What you have to do is read each line into a datastructure. Then call a function like split to split up spaces and split on ":" once you do that you should end up with an array or a map of values.

Then you can easily search though that.

Alternatively you can just check each line to see if it contains birds, but I think you will have more luck if you put  it into a datastructure first so you can more easily manipulate and use the data in the text file.